# Cannot see the wine ui

Tags: wine

I have the wine installed in my xubuntu machine, but when i try to open something like wine configuration i cannot see the ui for the wine.

when i do a 'ps -ef | grep wine' i get:

```
      21082  1944 86 14:10 ?        00:00:04 winecfg.exe                                      
      21086  1944  4 14:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/wineserver
      21096  1944  0 14:10 ?        00:00:00 C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe MountMgr                                          
      21116 16394  0 14:10 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto wine
```

but i cannot see anywhere the wine user interface.

p.s. I reinstall wine but the problem remains

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I run Ubuntu, not Xubuntu.  However, to address your issue I performed a fresh Xubuntu install.  After the install (by the way, I usually perform cli commands when possible).  I performed the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine
```

Then I found "Wine" in the dropdown menu.  Under Wine I found "Configure Wine".  Clicking on Configure Wine will bring up the configuration GUI.

This was done on Xubuntu 13.10.

If this doesn't work for you, I would suggest that you consider using the cli to install Wine:

Try these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge wine
$ sudo apt-get install wine
```

This should give you the defaults that I have.  If this fails there might be a problem with your Xubuntu install.

I'll be checking if there is a difference between this 13.10 install and the current 14.04.  If it find it's different I'll update this answer.